# Add salt to pycrypto KDF - useful?

Tags: pycrypto, pbkdf2

I have noted some sources indicate that when using a KDF like [PBKDF2](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Protocol/KDF.py) some advocate injecting the salt at the time of execution - like this:

```
dv = salt + PBKDF2(salt + password, salt)
```

Versus the "plain" usage of

```
dv = PBKDF2(password, salt)
```

When using the `PyCrypto.Protocol.KDF`  `PBKDF2` function (linked above), do the extra salt parameters add any benefit if no two passwords will have the same salt (but the salt will be stored with the password)?

Presumably the risk is having an oracle whereby identical passwords would be revealed as-such, encoded. Is this the case or is there another concern one ought to be mindful of?

If this is the only concern I would expect, in the absence of a fault in the algorithms that permits short-circuiting, a plainly used salt obliges one to recheck every password the entire number of iterations. Is this the case?

Comment: There is a reason KDF's have been designed with one argument for the password and one argument for the salt. It's to *avoid* having to deal with this kind of "insert salt here" ad hoc schemes. If doing this was beneficial in some way, don't you think PBKDF2 would be doing it already? Also, I am not sure whether I understand your point about identical passwords. Each password needs an individual salt, that is the whole point. I think this belongs on crypto.SE by the way, as it is a question about the theory of KDF's and salts (I've flagged it for migration)

Comment: Thanks Thomas for flagging- this would probably get better attention on crypto.SE.  Yes, both conceptually and mathematically I expect no benefit arises from the "insert salt here" but that being said crypto is an odd, finicky beast, and asking to be sure is fairly easy- since I have seen it mentioned in a few places now I figured it'd be worth getting a more authoritative answer.

Comment: Why is this marked off topic? From the FAQ, this concerns: "a specific programming problem" Yes. "a software algorithm" Yes. "software tools commonly used by programmers" Yes, hopefully. "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" Yes. That said, I don't disagree with a migration to Crypto.SE.

Comment: *Sigh* What can you do. Some people prefer to close than migrate. I suggest just reposting it over to crypto.SE, to be fair. Closing it like this is just not cool.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas - I guess it happens to every community over time.

Comment: Link to [this question on Crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/injecting-salt-into-pycrypto-kdf-useful)

Comment: @Thomas: Most users can't migrate, only ♦ mods can do that. [The last time I asked them about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160816/when-should-i-flag-off-topic-questions-for-migration), they seemed somewhat disinclined to migrate questions that weren't of particularly high quality. I suppose I can sort of see the point: for questions that haven't been answered yet, just closing them with a comment pointing to the appropriate site achieves essentially the same thing as migration, but without consuming the few and already busy moderators' time.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I see. Perhaps an automatic migration system where the question is automatically migrated after 3 or 5 medium-rep users have voted for migration could help, but I guess it has already been suggested before.

Comment: @Thomas: That actually exists, but it's sadly limited to a few specific target sites. (Currently, it seems one can vote to migrate questions from SO to meta.SO, SU, tex.SE, dba.SE and, for some reason, sharepoint.SE.) Also, it's kind of flawed in that having the privilege only depends on your rep _at SO_, not at the target site. (For example, IIRC, ServerFault used to be a valid migration vote target from SO, but apparently they asked to have that turned off because they were getting too many migrated questions that were off topic there too.)